# AWS AppSync gives Unauthorized Access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I want to read/write data into AWS AppSync DynamoDB thorugh python. I came across a solution online but it gives me an error:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = AWS4Auth(
    # An AWS 'ACCESS KEY' associated with an IAM user.
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    # The 'secret' that goes with the above access key.                    
    AWS_SECRET,    
    # The region you want to access.
    AWS_REGION_NAME,
    # The service you want to access.
    'appsync'
)
# As found in AWS Appsync under Settings for your endpoint.
APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = APPSYNC_ENDPOINT
# Use JSON format string for the query. It does not need reformatting.
query = """query MyQuery {
          getCustomer(id: "38c76f4f-c495-42e6-8599-647738a12692") {
            first_name
          }
        }"""
# Now we can simply post the request...
response = session.request(
    url=APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
    method='POST',
    json={'query': query}
)
print(response.text)
```

The following error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "UnauthorizedException",
    "message" : "You are not authorized to make this call."
  } ]
}
```

I have given Administrator Access to the IAM User. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the access credentials correspond to this IAM user?

Comment: Yes I have even created a new IAM user.

Comment: I'm stuck on same issue and never found a fix

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Here's the solution.
Due to changes in the authentication part of the generated GraphQL VTL by Amplify GraphQL Transformer v2, it was found that authentication from the backend Python does not pass, even if you set IAM Authorization rules in the @auth directive settings in schema.graphql.

```
The @auth directive settings in schema.graphql target only the IAM role generated by Amplify.
When adding IAM as an additional authentication provider in AppSync, it is necessary to create an allow list."
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#use-iam-authorization-within-the-appsync-console

Comment: How do you propose this should be fixed then?